# Iterating an ArrayList in nested for loop causing unexpected result

Tags: java, android, arraylist, expandablelistview

I want to implement Expandable Recycleview with Title and Some SubQuestions in Android I'm using [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view) Example.

I'm facing such issue on constructing the data for Expandable Adapter.

This is my Response from API

```
            [{
                "Label": "Title One",
                "Question": "SubQuestion One "
            },
            {
                "Label": "Title One"
                "Question": "SubQuestion Two"
            },
            {
                "Label": "Title Two",
                "Question": "SubQuestion Three"
            },
            {
                "Label": "Title Two",
                "Question": "SubQuestion Four"
            },
            {
                "Label": "Title Two",
                "Question": "SubQuestion Five"
            }]
```

I want to separate each Question with Label has Title One and the same as Title Two so I did below thing

Step 1: Creating ArrayList of Labels and removing a repetad item from ArrayList

```
for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++) {
ProgramDefinitionV1Days data = temp.get(j);
mAllTitlesList.add(data.getLabel());
}
mCompareTitlesList.clear();
mCompareTitlesList = removeDuplicates(mAllTitlesList);
```

Step 2: Comparing mCompareTitlesList with Original Response and get Questions by Label

```
for (String label : mCompareTitlesList) {
mQuetionsList.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
    if (label.equalsIgnoreCase(temp.get(i).getLabel())) {

        mQuetionsList.add(new Questions(temp.get(i).getQuestion()));
    }

}
Log.e("mQuetionsList", "" + new Gson().toJson(mQuetionsList));
Titles mTitles = new Titles(label, mQuetionsList);
mTitlesList.add(mTitles);
}
```

But unfortunately, I didn't get the Expected Result form it.

```
[{"mQuestions":[{"mQuestions":"Question Three"},{"mQuestions":"Question Four"},{"mQuestions":"Question Five"}],"mTitle":"Title One"},{"mQuestions":[{"mQuestions":"Question Three"},{"mQuestions":"Question Four"},{"mQuestions":"Question Five"}],"mTitle":"Title Two"}]
```

On Every Label has All Last label's Questions

What I Expect

```
[{"mQuestions":[{"mQuestions":"Question One"},{"mQuestions":"Question Two"}],"mTitle":"Title One"},{"mQuestions":[{"mQuestions":"Question Three"},{"mQuestions":"Question Four"},{"mQuestions":"Question Five"}],"mTitle":"Title Two"}]
```

Any Suggesions ?

Comment: What is your object Titles ? I would definitely go for an object Map<String, ArrayList<Questions>> and do the job in one foreach loop

Comment: Try replace: `mQuetionsList.clear();` with `ArrayList<Questions> mQuetionsList = new ArrayList<>();` Hope that helps!